# AS3 - Bitmap scales with html tag

Tags: actionscript-3, embed, flash

I developed a flash object with a bitmap (h/w=20/20) and a label aside the bitmap. My html code:

```
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="200" height="20" id="test" >
    <param name="movie" value="test.swf" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="data=testData" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <embed src="test.swf"
        width="200"
        height="20"
        name="test"
        quality="high"
        allowScriptAccess="always"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
        FlashVars="data=testData"
        wmode="transparent"
    />
</object>
```

So far so good but if I want to scale it down with html to e.g. `width="120" height="20"` the image gets scaled to h/w=20x12 and becomes ugly.

So how can I tell flash (or AS3?) to scale the width with the same modifier as the height or even better prevent the whole scaling of the image?

**EDIT:** to make it clear: the height and the width should always be scaled 1:1, so for e.g. if I double the height via html the width of the image should also double

Thanks guys!

Comment: Your description isn't very clear. Would it be possible to supply some images describing what is happening and what you want to happen?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you want, but you probably need to experiment with `StageScaleMode` and "allow smoothing" for your bitmap.